# Replacing driver door wiring harness 2012 Ford Escape

Tags: ford, wiring, escape, connector

I'm trying to replace the driver's door wiring harness on my 2012 Ford Escape, and I can't seem to get the main connector (at the hinge) disconnected.  Is there a trick to disconnecting this?  Do I really have to take apart the whole dash?

Here's the connector I'm having trouble with:

[image: 2012 Ford Escape driver's door wiring harness connector]

Here's a photo from the new connector I've ordered (haven't gotten it yet).

[image: Replacement cable]

Comment: Update: fairly certain the car was built around that connector.  It seems you somehow plug the car into the door, not the other way around.  Have removed the parking brake so far and still can't get to it due to the dumb way the holes are cut.

Answer (score 1):

It looks very similar to what is in this [video](https://youtu.be/UfHEHeQXmxE?t=183) -
I believe you need to press the tabs in (arrowed).  There are more on the far side of the connector that will need pressing in too.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately the connector in the video is different than mine.  Mine has a black attachment hold of some sort that I can't seem to get to.  The white part on the connector in my car does pull away from the body about an inch, but then gets caught (wires too short under the dash or something).

Comment: Maybe you need to unplug the connectors from the inside first.

Comment: Yep, working on it from that angle now.  Feels like Ford designed the whole car around that connection point.  I can see it now from the inside but still can't get to it